# Restrict generic_filter to specific axes

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, vectorization

Suppose I have an [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array of shape `(n,m)`. How can I apply a [generic filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#generic-filter-functions) over every 3 lines of this array, so that I end up with an array of shape `(n,)`?

The problem with

```
scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(input, function, size=3)
```

is that it returns an array of shape `(n,m)` because the filter is being applied to *every* element of the second axis, as opposed to once for every line. I can recover the result I want with

```
scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(input, function, size=(3,m))[:,0]
```

but this incurs a performance penalty because the work is being duplicated *for each column*. How can I make `generic_filter` act over the first axis and not the second one?

Comment: ?? [scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d.html#scipy-ndimage-generic-filter1d) ??

Comment: @wwii That takes every line in isolation and returns neighborhoods within that line, whereas I want neighborhoods *across* multiple lines.

Comment: ... `.generic_filter()` docs say it works elementwise.  Have you looked through all the other methods/functions?

Comment: Are you working with a specific `function`? If so, could you share?

Comment: Does your function require an array of shape (3, m)?  Can it accommodate a flattened array of shape (3 x m, )?

Comment: @Divakar The function is essentially a switch statement that maps every neighborhood of shape `(3,m)` to an output of shape `(m)`.

Comment: @wwii I suppose a flattened array of shape `(3*m)` is fine since I can just call `.reshape((3,m))` inside the function itself.

Comment: Do you need to use `.generic_filter` specifically? or are you just trying to apply your function to 3xm patches of the input?

Comment: @wwii I don't need to use `generic_filter` specifically. I'm just trying to apply the function to `(3,m)` patches as quickly and efficiently as possible. This is important because `n` and `m` are very large. Also, 3 could be replaced with a larger number.

Comment: You need to add more information to your question.  The actual/possible size of the array you are operating on, the number of arrays you are operating on, what you are actually trying to do, why you chose `.generic_filter()`, and the function you are trying to apply.  It is possible that the function itself could be *vectorised* but without it ...  There are other possible solutions but the lack of detail limits finding an optimal solution.

Comment: @wwii I'm simulating 3-component [cellular automata](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton), where `function` is the neighborhood transition function. So `function` is just a random function mapping `(3,m)` to `(m)` with no other internal structure. It shouldn't matter for the question though. I think the specification of what I'm looking for is pretty clear (applying a filter over some axes but not others).

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently create *sliding windows* from your array using the `sliding_window()` function at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23125520/2823755) or using [sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html).

`sliding_window()` allows you to set the step size.
The steps for `extract_patches` windows are the same size as the window.

Given

```
a = np.ones((6,4))
a = a + np.arange(6)[:, np.newaxis]

>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.]])

>>> 
>>> z = sliding_window(a, (3,4), ss = (1,4))
>>> for thing in z:
    print(thing, '\n******')

[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]] 
******
[[ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.]] 
******
[[ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.  5.]] 
******
[[ 4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.  5.]
 [ 6.  6.  6.  6.]] 
******
```

You still need to loop over the windows to apply the function

```
>>> def func(a):
    return a.sum()

>>> [func(a) for a in z]
[24.0, 36.0, 48.0, 60.0]
>>>
```

Or possibly, depending on the function

```
>>> np.sum(z, (1,2))
array([ 24.,  36.,  48.,  60.])
>>>
```

---

Unless I have totally misunderstood your problem,

I hope that is close to what you were trying to achieve.

Another option might be to reshape your array to `(n//3, 3*m)` then use [`generic_filter1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter1d)